# Log4rs JsonEncoder using yaml based configuration

Tags: logging, rust

How do I specify when using a `yaml` based configuration for [`log4rs`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/latest/log4rs/index.html) for the encoder to be the `json`  instead of `pattern`?

For Example, let's say my `log4rs.yml` file is the following, which logs `stdout` to the console and also to the log file `log/requests.log`

```yaml
refresh_rate: 30 seconds

appenders:
  stdout:
    kind: console

  requests:
    kind: file
    path: "log/requests.log"
    encoder:
      pattern: "{d} - {m}{n}"

root:
  level: warn
  appenders:
    - stdout
    - requests
```

And then starting up within the `main.rs` with the following:

```rust
log4rs::init_file("log4rs.yml", Default::default()).unwrap();
```

Instead of the `requests` appender using the `pattern` format, how can I set it to output using `json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the encoder for the requests appender to output using json, you can modify the encoder field as follows:

```
encoder:
  kind: json
```

This will tell Log4rs to use the json encoder for the requests appender. You can also specify additional options for the json encoder, such as the fields to include in the json output. For example:

```
encoder:
  kind: json
  fields:
    - { field: "level", value: "%l" }
    - { field: "timestamp", value: "%d" }
    - { field: "message", value: "%m" }
```

This will include the log level, timestamp, and message fields in the `json` output.

For more information on configuring the json encoder and other encoders in Log4rs, you can refer to the documentation:

https://docs.rs/log4rs/latest/log4rs/struct.JsonEncoder.html

Comment: Hi! Does this not work anymore? The link is broken and syntax is not working.